# Probability of picking 4 red balls one by one?

Tags: probability

> There are 3 red balls and 2 blue balls in a jar. You pick any 4 balls
> without looking in the jar. What is the probability that you would be
> having 4 red balls in hand?

Note that you are picking balls one by one means after picking one you put that ball in the jar and again pick another ball without looking and by this way you have to pick 4 red balls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer would be: $(\frac{3}{5})^4$ since each time the probability of picking a red ball is $\frac{3}{5}$ and you need this to happen $4$ times while the events are independent since you will put back the ball you pick each time.